# How to find remainder of a division in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

I'm trying to get the remainder of a division using Ruby.

Let's say we're trying to divide 208 by 11.

The final should be "18 with a remainder of 10"...what I ultimately need is that `10`.

Here's what I've got so far, but it chokes in this use case (saying the remainder is `0`).

```
division = 208.to_f / 11
rounded = (division*10).ceil/10.0
remainder = rounded.round(1).to_s.last.to_i
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The modulo operator:

```
> 208 % 11
=> 10
```

Comment: How the HECK did I make it so complicated? Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but it's not an operator, but a method of the `Fixnum` class: `>> 208.%(11) #=> 10`

Comment: @MichaelKohl Technically all ruby "operators" are methods. For example, `5 + 5` is really just shorthand for `5.+(5)`.

Comment: @fbonetti not all... `&`, `|`, `and`, `not`, and a few other operators are not methods.

Comment: @penne12 That's not entirely true. `&`, `|` are methods on `Fixnum`; they are NOT operators: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-26.

Comment: @penne12 here's a complete list of all ruby keywords: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/Rubysreservedwords.htm

Comment: @fbonetti sorry - I meant `&&` and `||`

Answer (score 59):

If you need just the integer portion, use integers with the `/` operator, or the [`Numeric#div`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-div) method:

```
quotient = 208 / 11
#=> 18

quotient = 208.0.div 11
#=> 18
```

If you need just the remainder, use the `%` operator or the [`Numeric#modulo`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo) method:

```
modulus = 208 % 11
#=> 10

modulus = 208.0.modulo 11
#=> 10.0
```

If you need both, use the [`Numeric#divmod`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) method. This even works if either the receiver or argument is a float:

```
quotient, modulus = 208.divmod(11)
#=> [18, 10]

208.0.divmod(11)
#=> [18, 10.0]

208.divmod(11.0)
#=> [18, 10.0]
```

Also of interest is the [`Numeric#remainder`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-remainder) method. The differences between all of these can be seen in the [documentation for `divmod`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod).

Comment: The `divmod` method was exactly what I was looking for, needing both remainder and integer portion.

Answer (score 5):

please use [Numeric#remainder](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Numeric.html#method-i-remainder) because mod is not remainder

Modulo:

```
5.modulo(3)
#=> 2
5.modulo(-3)
#=> -1
```

Remainder:

```
5.remainder(3)
#=> 2
5.remainder(-3)
#=> 2
```

here is the link discussing the problem
https://rob.conery.io/2018/08/21/mod-and-remainder-are-not-the-same/

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with the claim that there is a uniqe definition for remainder and modulo. There are implementations in programming languages - a modulo in algebra is related, but not the same. Note that  11 = 3 mod 4 in algebra, and not 11 mod 4 = 3.

Comment: I must disagree with @Zane's above claim.
In algebra, the expression `11 = 3 mod 4` does not contain an operator;`mod` is not an operator here. It's merely a description of the number system for `3`. To avoid confusion, it'd even be typically written `11 = 3 (mod 4)`.

Comment: @AdamSibik. I don't know why you think you "must disagree". From my point of your view, your remark supports the claim: there is no unique definition.